# Mysql/Apache weird cpu performance pattern

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.4

I've been struggling with a performance issue on one of my server for a few weeks.

Configuration: Dedicated server with Ubuntu 16.04, Mysql 5.7.21 (all MyISAM), Apache 2.4.18 (mpm prefork), Php 7.0.25. 128GB Ram

The cpu usage pattern is really weird and I've found nothing explaining it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/88VMm.jpg

As you can see, there are those successive levels of cpu usage, which are pretty constant. Also, when Apache cpu usages increases, Mysql usage cpu increases, and when one decreases, the other one decreases. Also, as you can see, the whole difference happens in CPU system usage.

I've had a look at the number of queries/s of mysql, which is basically constant. Same thing for the number of requets/s on apache2. Pretty constant. Btw the apache server takes around 100req/s and mysql is ~300queries/s on mysql (so the spikes in cpu does not seem to be linked to a regular high amount of requests on apache or mysql)

I have ahd a look at slow queries, nothing in particular. When I do a SHOW PROCESSLIST, no query is still around. Same thing for apache. Maximum page load time is <1s.

When I restart the apache2 service the pattern seems to disappear for a few hours. When I restart the mysql service, the pattern seems to disappear for a few hours too.

Also, I have a few other java services which also use this db (using the latest jdbc driver, and I don't see any cpu pattern change with them). There were initially creating their connection to mysql at the start of the services, but I changed this behavior to close the connection/start a new one every 5min ... This did not change anything

My my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
key_buffer_size = 36G
max_allowed_packet = 64M
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
max_connections = 512
table_open_cache = 8192
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 512M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
sort_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 36G
sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer = 4M
write_buffer = 4M
```

My apache has pretty much the default configuration, except it has (i can have about 350 workers used, that's why I put this value)

```
MaxRequestWorkers 1024
ServerLimit 1024
```

I'm really not sure what to do next to investigate.

Any idea of what could be going wrong ?

Thanks !

Edit: I did not see anything suspicious in apache or mysql logs

Edit: 
Some data asked in the comments

ulimit -a:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 514833
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 50000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 514833
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

iostat -x

```
Linux 4.4.0-112-generic (ns340707.ip-37-187-250.eu)     02/21/2018      _x86_64_        (12 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          14.89    0.29   10.42    1.41    0.00   72.98

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.70    51.90   18.37   11.86  1179.98  1894.25   203.33     1.40   46.40   10.29  102.33   2.35   7.11
sda               0.73    51.89   25.27   11.87  1847.55  1894.25   201.50     1.22   32.72    4.37   93.05   2.14   7.93
md0               0.00     0.00    9.63   62.19   758.90  1889.96    73.77     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
nvme1n1           0.00     0.00  429.64 1214.09  4755.77  6215.04    13.35     0.36    0.19    0.18    0.19   0.03   5.00
md2               0.00     0.00 1567.33 1204.69 14913.87  6204.69    15.24     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00 1204.85 1215.25 10676.20  6219.68    13.96     1.57    0.62    0.14    1.10   0.05  11.93
```

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS -> https://pastebin.com/AehMqQQq

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES -> https://pastebin.com/JyGquqFx

Mysql tuner output: https://pastebin.com/F8wvbHec

**I just noticed that, during those "high system cpu" phase, I have a high % of cpu in isolate_freepages_block** (I got that using `perf top`). Nevertheless I'm not sure how to solve this

Comment: Can you provide a longer time-period of your graph containing a httpd/mysql restart and maybe memory statistics?

Comment: What memory statistics do you want ?

Comment: @Nisalon How much RAM is on your server?  Dedicated or Shared?  Please post complete results of :  A)  ulimit -a   B) iostat -x  C) complete my.cnf/ini.  Thanks

Comment: Store on pastebin.com if needed and give us the links.
Please post complete text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete current text of error log
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
E) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop   OR  top for most active apps
MySQLTuner.com  entire report
Why entire report? Because the report includes V nn, RAM, per Engine analysis of data space/table counts 
and additional very helpful information.

Comment: Post updated. Please note that i'm using myisam and not innodb

Comment: its not clear to me what you are saying the problem is... is it slow page load times? (you mention it was max 1s, so that seems reasonable)

Comment: No, juste a weird cpu pattern, which makes me fear getting more load on that server.

Comment: Questions #1 
Maximum time allowed for User Inactivity before CONNECTION should be disconnected? nnn SECONDS/MINUTES/HOURS  
   Does your application have Logout/Signoff available to user? Yes or No - if No, how are resources released?
   Login will be required to get back online after disconnection (and resources will again be consumed).
Is connection pooling in use?  Yes or No   will likely influence a few php.ini settings

Comment: Questions #2
Rotating HD  nnn of Spindles,  nnn TB/GB/MB and  nnn TB/GB/MB Free Space
SSD  nnn TB/GB and  nnn TB/GB/MB Free Space of SSD    Random Write mfg or tested IOPS? _________ not read seq or RR.
nnn TB/GB/MB row count limit for SQL SELECT, JOIN, SORT, etc. for a single query processing limit
Do you really want to allow one query to SELECT a billions rows of information before concluding this is a MISTAKE?
Depending on your application, a Billion rows could be fine.
HOSTED on what system? ___________  pendo.io, AWS, Google, In-house, local area hosting organization.

Comment: @Nisalon  a few days ago, you mentioned ' I changed this behavior to close the connection/start a new one every 5min ... '  has this logic been removed?  Closing connection/start every 5 min seems unnecessary.

Comment: There is no "user" concept in the application. 

I have 2 NVMe SSD in raid1

Answer (score 0):

These are all Dynamic variables that may be set with SET GLOBAL xxx=xxx;
please follow requested order.  If you only do ONE a day, shutdown restart,
you are many days away, but then you are running very well.
RESEARCH and pursue as time permits, 
weird usage pattern will likely go away during this cycle of tuning.

Suggestions for your my.cnf/ini [mysqld] section

```
max_connections=325  #from 512 to support 270 max_used_connections
#max_allowed_packet=64M  # lead for 1M default  WHEN YOU NEED more
```

at start of your SESSION, only when you need it,
SET @max_allowed_packet=67108864  # to reduce RAM footprint MySQLTuner reported

```
query_cache_size=0  # from 16M, not being used, conserve RAM
query_cache_limit=1K  # from 1M, conserve RAM
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  #from 4096, for > results stored, if ever used
thread_cache_size=100  # from 8 to reduce ~ 240,000 threads_created a day
```

the next 3 (do all 3 on one day) will enhance MyISAM key_buffer management

```
key_cache_division_limit=50  # from 100 default  for Hot/Warm separation
key_cache_block_size=64K  # from 1K let's clear more RAM when full
key_cache_age_threshold=64800  # from 300 KEEP 18 HRS vs 5M to reduce RD RPS

innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 to conserve CPU cycles
innodb_stats_sample_pages=32  # from 8 to improve statistics cardinality
max_seeks_for_key=32  # from a huge # to limit OPTIMIZER depth
max_write_lock_count=16  # from a huge # to allow RD after NN write locks
table_open_cache=16000  # from 8192 to support ~ 350,000 opened_tables daily
```

If you have any SSD, there are more opportunities.  Asked in a comment a day or so ago.

Comment: @nisalon  Have you made any progress with management of this server?  Please share your success or current problems.  Thank you for posting your information to allow these Suggestions to be provided in February.  See my profile for contact information, please.  A new Question should be opened for current concerns, this one has enough baggage.

Comment: @nisalon  Has your weird cpu performance pattern improved since February?  I any comments or answers helped, please upvote and possibly accept answer so we have some indication of helpfulness.  Please view profile, Network profile for contact info including my Skype ID.  Please get in touch.

Comment: @nisalon  Guessing you just do not want us to know if you are making any progress or not, since upvotes are not evident and no feedback.  The very BEST to you.

Comment: @nisalon  With 2 NVME's in my.cnf [mysqld] section 

innodb_io_capacity=20000  # to allow higher IOPS

will help.

Comment: @nisalon  Have you resolved your rough patch with MySQL?  Let us know, please.

Answer (score 0):

- Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.  (And change `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.)
- Lower `MaxRequestWorkers 1024` and `max_connections = 512` -- It is better to stop new people from entering the grocery store than have the store so crowded that no one can move.  Even `270 Max_used_connections` may indicate 'thundering herd'.
- The Query cache is *probably* hurting more than helping.  In busy production systems, with lots of *writes*, the QC needs to be flushed a lot.  So, independent of other tests, change to `query_cache_type=0` and `query_cache_size=0`.
- Check on Java's garbage collection.

I'll be happy to review `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and `SHOW VARIABLES` it you repost them (they have expired).